# How to manage Facebook API response data

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing an app for iPhone and I am sending this URL to Facebook:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

and the Facebook reply something like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "2081746282701",
         "from": {
            "name": "USER1",
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
         },
         "place": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "name": "\u03a0\u03b1\u03bb\u03bb\u03ac\u03b4\u03b9\u03bf",
            "location": {
               "city": "xxxxxxxx",
               "country": "Greece",
               "latitude": xxxxx,
               "longitude":xxxxx
            }
         },
         "application": {
            "name": "Facebook for iPhone",
            "id": "6628568379"
         },
         "created_time": "2011-05-25T01:22:00+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id":"xxxxxx",
                  "name": TaggedUsers"
               },
               {
                  "id": "xxxxxx",
                  "name": "tagged user"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "xxxxxxx",
         "from": {
            "name": "UserWhich puplish this",
            "id": "740646984"
         },
         "tags": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "XXXXXX",
                  "id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
               }
            ]
         },
         "place": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "name": "xxxxxxxx",
            "location": {
               "latitude": xxxxxx,
               "longitude": xxxxxx
            }
         },
         "application": {
            "name": "Facebook for Android",
            "id": "350685531728"
         },
         "created_time": "2011-05-23T17:18:54+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "xxxxxxx",
                  "name": "xxxxxxxxx"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
}
```

My question is how I will manage this string to export long lat place and the user who checked in? I think that `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` wont do the trick because there is no unique variable to search for. For example the "data" is placed at the start of the responded string and before of each check in but its placed and before tagged user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [JSON](http://www.json.org/): JavaScript Object Notation.

You can decode it easily into a NSDictionary or NSArray with the [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) depending on the root element. After that it's a tree like structure depending on the JSON returned.

The mentioned framework provides an easy to use category for NSObject which offers the method JSONValue.

Example to decode the json you'v received:

```
NSString *myJson = @"...";
NSDictionary *decodedJson = [myJson JSONValue];
```

Now you can use fast enumeration or direct access(`objectForKey:`) to retrieve the data you are interested in.

```
NSArray *users = [decodedJson objectForKey:@"data"];

foreach(NSDictionary *user in users =) {
    NSLog(@"user's id: %@", [user objectForKey:@"id"]);
    NSDictionary *fromData = [user objectForKey:@"from"]);
    NSLog(@"user is from: %@", [fromData objectForKey:@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"user is from id: %@", [fromData objectForKey:@"id"]);
    // and so on ..
}
```

Comment: I have followed the instrunctions(download it and copy all the classes under my project) and I am getting compiling 8 errors.

Comment: @user622203 you should post this problem in a new question. I am using the json-framework with XCode4.

Comment: OK i fixed the 7 of them by copying the classes into the same folder that the appViewcontroller is located but now I am getting this error: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: OK when I will check it I will give you the answer

Comment: @user622203 I don't understand you, what do you mean by "not what expecting"?

Comment: This method just convert the string to something else but it still difficult to manage this string. I want to select 2 users from this string but using NSCaseSensitive is to difficult. Json method doesnt make it easier!

Comment: @user622203 you should get more into using json and accessing it with dictionaries and arrays. String searches are hard to maintain and are very volatile to changes, especially if it's not your API changing.

Comment: @user622203 I've added some example code how to iterate through your users. However, I did not check the code, so be forgiving on it. Believe me, parsing XML can be very painful. JSON is a good format to transport structured data. As you've seen in your other question, the facebook sdk uses the json-framework too.